# mocking my fetch function does not work, keeps getting back undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, fetch

I am trying to mock a simple function that uses fetch. The function in question looks like this:

```
export const getPokemon = async () => {
  //function that makes the API call and fetches our pokemon
//getPokemon.js
  const randomId = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 151 + 1);

const pokemonApiUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/`;

export const getPokemon = async () => {
  //function that makes the API call and fetches our pokemon
  const id = randomId();
  let pokemon = { name: "", image: "" };
  try {
    const result = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
    console.log(result)
    const data = await result.json();
    pokemon.name = data.name;
    pokemon.image = data.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default;
    return pokemon;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
```

Whenever I try to mock the function in my unit tests I receive back a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined`. Basically, the `result` comes back as `undefined` and thus we cannot call our `.json()`. It works fine in production and the fetch calls work as expected. I am using React Testing Library and Jest.

I have tried to replaced the global fetch in the following manner:

```
//PokemonPage.test.js
global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve({ data: { name: 'Charizard' } }),
  })
);
```

I've also tried to create a `fakeFetch` and send it in to my function as a dependency injection, but I get the exact same error.

Lastly, I've tried to install `jest-fetch-mock` but yet again I am getting the same error... Has anyone encountered the same thing?

The failing function gets called in production here:

```
function Pokemon({ pokemonTrainer }) {
...
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      pokemonRef.current = await getPokemon();
      setPokemonList((prev) => [
        ...prev,
        { name: pokemonRef.current.name, image: pokemonRef.current.image },
      ]);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
...
}
```